# What is python's termios module in Windows?

Tags: python

First, the code (which I found here: https://github.com/defaultxr/taptempo.py/blob/master/taptempo.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import tty
import termios
from time import time
from sys import stdin


def getchar():
    fd = stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(stdin.fileno())
        ch = stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch


def addtime(times):
    if type(times) != list:
        raise(TypeError)
    t = time()
    if len(times) == 0:
        tdiff = 0  # initial seed
    else:
        tdiff = t - times[-1][0]
    return (t, tdiff)


def averagetimes(times):
    averagetime = sum([row[1] for row in times])/float(len(times))
    bpm = (1.0/(averagetime/60.0))
    return (averagetime, bpm)


def main():
    print('Tap a key on each beat. Press q to quit.', end='\r')

    times = []
    while True:
        char = getchar()
        if char in ('q', 'Q', '\x1b', '\x03'):  # q, Q, ESC, Control+C
            print()
            quit()

        times.append(addtime(times))
        if len(times) > 1:
            # remove first element if it's either the initial seed
            # or when the list reaches max length
            if times[0][1] == 0 or len(times) > 16:
                del times[0]
            (averagetime, bpm) = averagetimes(times)

            print("\rDetected BPM: %0.3f (Avg time between each: %0.3fs)"
                  % (bpm, averagetime), end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get an error saying, "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement termios ERROR: No matching distribution found for termios"

After some research, it turns out, termios comes with Python, but it is not included in the windows distribution (it's only in Linux), since another utility called "Airflow" is also not in windows.

I'm a musician and it looks like a nice very lightweight little app, which would be great for "tempo tapping".  Larger programs that include tempo tappers are usually too bulky and unnecessary and sometimes a little slow.  So I was just wondering if there is a way I could to get that little app to work in windows?

It's an interesting question, anyway.  I have never run across such a "conflict" (if it could be called that) between Windows and Linux in Python.

Comment: you could use pynput to listen for kbhit like termios is doing ...